# Jquery - Show the div after the element hover

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to show on input hover the div after the input element.

My html :

```
<div>
  <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
  <div class="popup">Small text popup</div>
</div>
```

My jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':input[type="text"]'.hover(
    function(){$(this).siblings("div:first").show();},
    function(){$(this).siblings("div:first").hide();}
  );
});
```

But it's not working yet, what's wrong or how can i do this (jquery, not css) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code, missing `)` in your selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':input[type="text"]').hover(
    //                 ----^----
    function() {
      $(this).siblings("div:first").show();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).siblings("div:first").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
  <div class="popup">Small text popup</div>
</div>
```

You can use **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** to get immediately  following sibling

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':input[type="text"]').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).next().show();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).next().hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
  <div class="popup">Small text popup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, how hide by default the div ?

Comment: write css display:none; in class popup

Answer (score 1):

You can use a full css solution using the adjacent sibling selector `+`.

```css
input[type="text"]:hover+.popup{
  display: block;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
  <div class="popup">Small text popup</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach to achieve what you want with this one even if you have more than one sibling div's for your popover you can show the same result.(as it might possible that in future you can add other elements in same parent of that popover div).
your code will not be restricted to the index of your div inside DOM or parent the is first our second child.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':input[type="text"]').hover(function() {
    $('#popover').show();
  }, function() {
    $('#popover').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#popover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  top: 21px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
  <div>sample text</div>
  <div>sample text</div>
  <div id="popover">Small text popover</div>
  <div>sample text</div>
  <div>sample text</div>
  <div>sample text</div>
</div>
```